# "application-status" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, canonical-questions

There is a very good chance that all incoming questions about how to know the status of a UK visa application can be marked as a duplicate as soon as it is posted. If you see a new (UK) question about this, please close vote it as a duplicate of 
[How to track my UK Visa Application Status?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36115/how-to-track-my-uk-visa-application-status)

There are 11 questions in the archives with the [application-status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-status) tag and about 7 of them are UK, hence duplicates.

So should I go through them and initiate a close vote on them?

If so, I would be close voting questions that were posted in the past, is it OK?

If I'm close voting an old question, should I leave a comment about it?

Normally I like to comment on NEW questions when I close vote something (on advice from my TSE guru, Mark), you probably have seen some of them.

But does it make sense if the OP is long gone?

Comment: Who on earth voted to close your canonical as too old to migrate?

Answer (score 4):

I think that especially now that we're getting bigger we can see which questions are asked the most often and what their variations are.

This means we can make purposefully designed canonical questions and answer to cover them.

This is a good thing. It'll basically be an FAQ.

We could even use the terms "FAQ" and "canonical" in these as a pseudo-standard.

Comment: Do you mean have a tag called 'faq' and another one called 'canonical'?

Comment: No, I thought about that briefly but those would be "meta tags" which is something Stack Exchange specifically doesn't like. Probably just including using a term in the QA title like "FAQ on Europe safety" or "Canonical question and answer for bringing electronics into India".

Comment: @pnuts: That's an OK idea but the tag wikis have very low visibility when browsing the site. They might be well-indexed by search engines, I'm not sure. If we make sure they have lots of links in and out then Google will definitely index them well. And that's a major factor for Stack Exchange that I hope we are all aware of.

Answer (score 0):

> So should I go through them and initiate a close vote on them?

Yes please. (If not all now Closed you might want to mention which are not.)

> If so, I would be close voting questions that were posted in the past, is it OK?

Yes.

> If I'm close voting an old question, should I leave a comment about it?

No need where the VTC is for duplication - if enough votes accumulate for that reason the system will generate a notice automatically.

> But does it make sense if the OP is long gone?

Commenting in such a situation does not make sense, just wastes your precious time.